# Try and Catch laravel it's not working for me

Tags: php, laravel, validation, try-catch

i've a little problem, I'm trying to add the validations (Try and Catch) on my laravel project, the problem is that in some controllers works fine, but in a specific doesn't work, the validation is when try to load a page, and something went wrong, the aplication will redirect the user to another stable page with a message; here's my code:

```
public function info($id)
{
    try {
        $likes = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[0];
        $dislikes = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[1];
        $downloads = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[4];
        $favorite = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[5];
        $myLike= $this->interactionAndUser($id)[2];
        $myDisLike = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[3];
        $book = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[6];
        $fileExistEpub = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[9];
        $fileExistPdf = $this->interactionAndUser($id)[10];
        $books = Book::find($id);
        $forum = Forum::where('book_id', $id)->first();
        $forumId = $forum->id;
        $forumTheme = $forum->theme_id;
        $forumHasTheme = Theme::where('id', $forumTheme)->first();   
        $comments = Comment::where(['forum_id' => $forumId, 'comment_id' => null])
        ->paginate(5);
       if(Cache::has($id)==false) { // Si el ID tiene un valor falso o 0 para el cache, agregue 1
            Cache::add($id, 'contador', 0.05); // Cada 0.05 segundos se contara una nueva visita por usuario, que recargue la pagina
            $book->views+=1;
            $book->save();
        }
        return view('books/info', compact('books', 'book', 'likes', 'dislikes', 'favorite', 'downloads', 'myLike', 'myDisLike', 'forum', 'forumHasTheme', 'comments', 'fileExistEpub', 'fileExistPdf'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('books')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
    } 
    } -> This code work perfectly
```

As you can see, is a simple validation of the exception of Laravel, this works well, if something went wrong, the user will be redirect to another stable page, this piece of code is in a controller called BookController, the problem is with FrontController, and another function, when I try pass the validation, never redirect the user to a stable page; here my code

```
 public function info_novelty($id)
  {
    try {
      $novelty = Novelty::find($id);
      return view('news.show', compact('novelty'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('noticias')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
    }
  } -> This validation doesn't work
```

I don't know why happens this, if someone can help me, I'll be really gratefull

And this is the error that I got it

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/Code/Biblio/resources/views/news/show.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [findOrFail()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_findOrFail) method to ensure an exception is thrown if the resource is not found for the given id.

If no resource is found, the `findOrFail()` method will throw a `ModelNotFoundException`, so your code can look for it specifically:

```
try {
      $novelty = Novelty::findOrFail($id);
      return view('news.show', compact('novelty'));
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        // return more specific error message
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('noticias')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
    }
```